# How to slide 2 small pieces of metal into each other

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

I'm trying to build a keyboard addon for my smartphone (https://gitlab.com/xengi/mkbd65). The last challenge I'm facing is how the two pieces, namely the smartphone and the keyboard should slide back and forth.
I know I need some kind of linear slider.

Something like that: http://en.smoothgroup.cc/goods/detail/58.htm

How would I construct or implement something like that? Is there a better way to do it? What do I need to consider which I maybe haven't thought about?

I don't think I'm able to do something like that: http://phonesdata.com/files/models/Nokia-N950-482.jpg

So my goal is to build something like that: http://phonesdata.com/files/models/Nokia-N900-684.jpg

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Buy the part.  If you try to do it from scratch, you'll have to learn about dissimilar material galling, thermal stability, fab tolerancing, and a lot more.

Comment: Oh, maybe you got me wrong there. I don't want to do that myself. I know that it's the easiest do just by the part. My question was more like. Which one should I buy (not only which brand but also which type and are there even different types)? Is this the best solution to do that or are there easier ways to do it?